# error: 'cvSVD' is not a member of 'cv'

Tags: c++, opencv

```
    cv::reduce(X, ux, 1, CV_REDUCE_AVG);
    cv::reduce(Y, uy, 1, CV_REDUCE_AVG);
    sigmx2 = normv(X * K) * 1 / n;
    SXY = Y * K * X.t() * 1 / n;
//    cv::SVD::compute(SXY, D, U, V);
    cv::cvSVD(&SXY, &D, &U, &V);
//    cv::SVD::compute(SXY, U, D, V);
```

When I debug, the following err appeared:

```
/home/allanna/Code/test_rpnp/rpnp.cpp:397:5: error: 'cvSVD' is not a member of 'cv'
     cv::cvSVD(&SXY, &D, &U, &V);
```

I already include the

```
#include <opencv2/core/core_c.h>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
```

After I took out the cv:: before cvSVD, the following code appear:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file /home/allanna/Library/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/src/matrix.c‌​pp, line 880 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
```

How to solve it? Thank u.

Comment: The result of the two function is not the same. SVD::SVD() won't give the right singular vector, which is I needed. And I aready find the error. The cv:: before cvSVD should be took out.

Comment: I'm not a familiar with OpenCV, but according to [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvsvd#svd-compute) you probably need to use C++ `compute` function instead of C `cvSVD`. Nevertheless did you try `::cvSVD` call (i.e. from global namespace)?

Comment: Yeah, I tried. I just took out cv::. What's refer to call from global namespace. After I took out the cv::,  the following code appear: OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file /home/allanna/Library/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 880
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'